# Conversion from type dbnull to type double is not valid

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

```
<!-- Function 1-->   
 
Function GetStudentResultTotal(ByVal schid As String, ByVal level As String, ByVal session As String, ByVal term As String, ByVal klass As String, ByVal regno As String) As Double
        If SCH_ID <> "" Then
            schid = SCH_ID
        End If
        Dim total As Double = 0
        Dim subjectCount As Integer = 0
        Dim fields As New ArrayList
        fields.Add("SUM(" & StudentData.Total & ") AS GrandTotal")
        Dim filterValues As New Hashtable
        filterValues.Add(StudentData.SchoolID, schid)
        filterValues.Add(StudentData.Level, level)
        filterValues.Add(StudentData.Session, session)
        filterValues.Add(StudentData.Term, term)
        filterValues.Add(StudentData.Klass, klass)
        filterValues.Add(StudentData.RegNo, regno)
        Dim filterArgs As String = "WHERE " & StudentData.SchoolID & "=@" & StudentData.SchoolID & " AND " & StudentData.Level & "=@" & StudentData.Level & " AND " & StudentData.Session & "=@" & StudentData.Session & " AND " & StudentData.Term & "=@" & StudentData.Term & " AND " & StudentData.Klass & "=@" & StudentData.Klass & " AND " & StudentData.RegNo & "=@" & StudentData.RegNo
        Dim data As DataSet = _Data.GetData(StudentData.tblStudentResult, fields, filterValues, filterArgs)
        'If data.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        '    For Each dr As DataRow In data.Tables(0).Rows
        '        total += CDbl(NormalizeRecord(dr(StudentData.Total)))
        '        subjectCount += 1
        '    Next
        'End If
        Dim dr As DataRow = data.Tables(0).Rows(0)
        total = CDbl(dr("GrandTotal"))
        Return total
    End Function

<!-- Function 2-->  

  Function GetData(ByVal tbl As String, ByVal values As ArrayList, ByVal filters As Hashtable, ByVal filterArgs As String) As DataSet
        Dim _ds As New DataSet
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT "
        Dim fields As String = ""
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
            conn.Open()
            If values IsNot Nothing Then
                For i = 0 To values.Count - 1
                    If fields = "" Then
                        fields = values.Item(i).ToString
                    Else
                        fields &= "," & values.Item(i).ToString
                    End If
                Next
                sql &= fields & " "
            End If
            sql &= "FROM " & tbl
            If filterArgs <> "" Then
                sql &= " " & filterArgs
            End If
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            If filters IsNot Nothing Then
                For i = 0 To filters.Count - 1
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & filters.Keys(i), filters.Values(i))
                Next
            End If
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(_ds)
            conn.Close()
        End Using
        Return _ds
    End Function


<!-- Function 3-->  
Function NormalizeRecord(ByVal value As String) As String
        If value = "-" Then
            value = "0"
        End If
        Return value
    End Function
```

Function 1 as described in my code is supposed to sum the column total and return the result but it always throw error (Conversion from type dbnull to type double is not valid) if it returns null value especially when am inserting record for the first time. how can i control null value?

Comment: You first need to determine what your sql that you are sending to the server looks like, and then run that directly and examine your results.

Comment: You first need to determine what your sql that you are sending to the server looks like, and then run that directly and examine your results.

Comment: Actual problem aside, bluntly can't help but think this is such an over complicated way to do a simple data retrieval task.  Generic data methods like seem like your GetData() a good idea, but more often than not just end up problematic than anything.  And also, not 100% sure the Where clause you're constructing is going to be correct (May actually be where your error is dependent on the values)

Comment: If your code blindly converts the result to a `Double` when it might not be a `Double` then of course it's going to fail. Maybe you should actually check whether the data is a `Double` first. This is just common sense, isn't it? Isn't that what you would do in a manual process? Why abandon the logic you use every day when you start writing code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways to deal with this.

First up, you might have no rows, or the ONLY row returned has a null value.

If you doing a "sum()", then if ANY of the rows are not null, then you WILL get a value back.

however, no rows, or rows with the column that are null, then you see/get/find a null.

So, one easy fix would be to use isnull.

So, your code could say use this:

```
.Add("IsNull(SUM(" & StudentData.Total & "),0) AS GrandTotal")
```

The above is probably your best bet, since EVEN if the query were to not even return any rows due to filter, you still get a 0 back.

***Edit: I see you tagged this as MySQL, and not SQL server - my mistake, so I suggest using below solution.***

however, often, in fact quite a bit, you will encounter null values in your data tables
(BTW, why are you using a dataset in place of a data table? You don't need a dataset here, since  you don't have a colleciton of tables).

So, next up, since you often have do to this?

Place in your "system wide" bag of utility routines this:

```
Public Function Nz(ByVal Value As Object, 
      Optional ByVal MyDefault As Object = "") As Object
    If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) Then
        Return MyDefault
    Else
        Return Value
    End If
End Function
```

So, now you can say do this:

```
total = nz(dr("GrandTotal"),0)
```

You could/can modify the SQL query, and have it return a 0 value for those null rows.